# Service number limit

Tags: google-app-engine

What is the maximum number of services that an App Engine Flex app can have?

I found this [site](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine), under [limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/an-overview-of-app-engine#limits) is the max number of services 5. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `Maximum services per application` that the documentation you linked refers to are **Backend services**. The limit is the number of backend services available to the GAE flex application. This applies to running versions of GAE.

Also, regarding the last part of the limits documentation:

> If you expect a notable upcoming increase in usage, you can proactively request adjustments from the App Engine Quotas page in the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails).

This means that you can request an increase for the maximum services your application have access to by going to the [GCP Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) and selecting `Compute Engine API` as Service. In the list of quotas you'll find the `Backend services` quota. With the current usage and the current limit. Select it and click `Edit quotas` to request an increase.